# How to handle "create database permission denied in database 'master' in windows authentication exception?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I opened "ASP.NET SQL Server Setup Wizard" using the command `apsnet_regsql` from visual studio 10 command propmpt(Run as Administrator).

In that wizard I selected `Windows Authentication` instead of `Sql Authentication`. When I tries to connect to Master Database I am getting the following exception

`An error occurred during the execution of the SQL file 'InstallCommon.sql'. The SQL error number is 262 and the SqlException message is: CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'. 
Creating the TestDB database`

and the SqlException is:

`create database permission denied in database 'master' in windows authenticAtion`.

I understand that I don't have permission to create database. But how and where can I give permission to do that.

So please help me and give a solution for my problem.Thanks.

Comment: see this post may be helpful to you http://blog.techdreams.org/2007/11/create-database-permission-denied-sql.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to login as a user who is a member of the `sysadmin` or `dbcreator` roles.

Comment: i am login the system with my admin credentials. how to change db roles?